# sqlalchemy fails to connect to db after server is idle for a few hours

Tags: firewall, postgresql, python

I have a fairly standard setup where the application server is separated by a firewall from the database server. The application is using sqlalchemy and the db is postgres.

The system works fine for a few hours, but once it remains idle for a long period it appears that the communication fails between the server and the db. The error log is:

```
WARNI [sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool.0x...7310] [worker 26] Error closing cursor: cursor already closed
```

I set up the connection pool with the 'pool_recylce' setting set to 30mins, so that there are no connections lingering for more than 30 mins. The problem persists.

any ideas?

Update:  I have posted the same question on stackoverflow and got an answer that worked. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592137/sqlalchemy-fails-to-connect-to-db-after-server-is-idle-for-a-few-hours

Comment: How exactly are you querying the database?  Can you give an example of your code where you're querying?  I.e., using SQLAlchemy's ORM, raw SQL, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to make sure that there are no active connections after half an hour of idling, e.g. with `netstat -tpn`. At least that will narrow down the problem to either (a) connections are still open so pool_recycle does not work as expected or (b) there are no open connections and the problem is elsewhere.